# UserControl properties and the WebPartsTemplate, values lost

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, web-parts

I'm trying to add UserControls to a webparts CatalogZone, but properties values that I assign to the controls are lost (or don't persist to the display) when the user selects the control to be added to the display. If I declare the same control definition explicitly in a WebPartZone, the property values persist. I've stepped through the code and found that when the controls that are selected from the CatalogZone and subsequently loaded from the personalization db, the values that I'd defined are lost/forgotten/abandoned. Please see my code below.

**TestPage.aspx**

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/TestControl.ascx"TagName="TestControl" TagPrefix="test"  %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:WebPartManager ID="WebPartManager1" runat="server">
</asp:WebPartManager>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlListModes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />  
<asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone1" runat="server">
    <ZoneTemplate>            
        <test:TestControl ID="TestControl1" runat="server" FontBold="true" />     
    </ZoneTemplate>
</asp:WebPartZone>
<asp:CatalogZone ID="CatalogZone1" runat="server">
    <ZoneTemplate>
        <asp:DeclarativeCatalogPart ID="dcp1" runat="server">
            <WebPartsTemplate>
                <test:TestControl ID="TestControl2" runat="server" FontBold="true" />  
            </WebPartsTemplate>
        </asp:DeclarativeCatalogPart>
    </ZoneTemplate>
</asp:CatalogZone>
</asp:Content>
```

So, in the above code, for TestControl1 defined in the WebPartZone.ZoneTemplate, the value for FontBold persists through control instantiation, and the usercontrol's font-bold property is set to true.

For TestControl2, defined in the CatalogZone.ZoneTemplate.DeclarativeCatalogPart.WebPartsTemplate the value for FontBold does not persist through control instantiation, and the usercontrol's FontBold value is never set.

I've tried using ViewState, ControlState,etc to save the value, thinking it wasn't persisting postbacks, but the problem lies before that, as the FontBold value is never set{}.

Any ideas?

Thanks for taking time to read and respond.

Ryan

The rest of the code

**TestPage.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class WebPartTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        Page.InitComplete += new EventHandler(BindDdlListModes);
        ddlListModes.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlListModes_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void BindDdlListModes(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebPartManager wpm = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(Page);
        string browseModeName = WebPartManager.BrowseDisplayMode.Name;

        ddlListModes.Items.Clear();

        foreach (WebPartDisplayMode mode in wpm.SupportedDisplayModes)
        {
            if (mode.IsEnabled(wpm))
            {
                ListItem item = new ListItem(mode.Name);
                ddlListModes.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        int index = ddlListModes.Items.IndexOf(ddlListModes.Items.FindByText(wpm.DisplayMode.Name));
        ddlListModes.SelectedIndex = index;
    }

    protected void ddlListModes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebPartManager wpm = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(Page);
        WebPartDisplayMode displayMode = wpm.SupportedDisplayModes[ddlListModes.SelectedValue];

        if (displayMode != null)
            wpm.DisplayMode = displayMode;

    }
}
```

**TestControl.ascx.cs** 
The control consists of only one label, which I'm setting the Font-bold value via the FontBold property.

```
public partial class TestControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{           
    public bool FontBold { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FontBold)
            lblText.Font.Bold = true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an opportunity to check right now, but it seems to me that the FoldBold property should be marked with the Personalizable(), WebBrowsable() attributes.